# Is there any usable dependency for virtuoso.jena.driver?

Tags: maven, jena, virtuoso

What I want to do is passing data from sesame to virtuoso.

Here are my codes:

```
public static void sesame2virtuoso(String server, String repo, String graphName) throws IOException, RepositoryException {

    //connect sesame
    HTTPRepository repository = new HTTPRepository(server, repo);
    repository.setUsernameAndPassword(PropertiesUtil.PropValues("user"), PropertiesUtil.PropValues("password"));
    repository.initialize();
    RepositoryConnection connection = repository.getConnection();
    ValueFactory factory = connection.getValueFactory();

    try {
        RepositoryResult<Statement> statements = connection.getStatements(null, null, null, false);
        Statement statement;
        String sub, pre, obj;
        VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph(graphName, URL, "dba", "dba");
        int count = 0;
        while (statements.hasNext()) {
            statement = statements.next();
            sub = statement.getSubject().stringValue();
            pre = statement.getPredicate().stringValue();
            obj = statement.getObject().stringValue();

            Node sub1 = Node.createURI(sub);
            Node pre1 = Node.createURI(pre);
            Node obj1 = Node.createURI(obj);
            try {
                graph.add(new Triple(sub1, pre1, obj1));                } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I used it in a maven project. So I searched some poms for that, but all of them can't work.

[image]

I think the reason is the dependencies versions are wrong or something wrong happened with my idea IDE. What should I do?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How you find the virtuoso artifact ? They are not available on maven central so you have to add external artifact repository (issue open in github : https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/249)

Comment: I found them from some people's github. Thanks for your answer. It helps me. @colinaygalinc

Comment: The image here, that holds only text, would be much better replaced by that text...  Toward your question, certainly the values in your `<version>` entities are incorrect.  I wonder also about some of the `<groupId>` and `<artifactId>` values.

Comment: Please also add your voice to [the relevant open issues on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/search?q=maven&state=open&type=Issues).

Answer (score 2):

These libraries ( `virt_jena3.jar`  and `virtjdbc4.jar`) do not exist in any public maven repository.

It's not your fault, is the Openlink people's fault.

If you want them, here are the steps.

### 1. Download them on your computer

```
wget http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/virtuoso/rdfproviders/jena/30/virt_jena3.jar -P /tmp/
wget http://download3.openlinksw.com/uda/virtuoso/jdbc/virtjdbc4.jar -P /tmp/
```

### 2. Install them in your local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -q \
 -Dfile=/tmp/virt_jena3.jar \
 -DgroupId=com.openlink.virtuoso \
 -DartifactId=virt_jena3 \
 -Dversion=3.0 \
 -Dpackaging=jar \
 -DgeneratePom=true

mvn install:install-file -q \
 -Dfile=/tmp/virtjdbc4.jar \
 -DgroupId=com.openlink.virtuoso \
 -DartifactId=virtjdbc4 \
 -Dversion=4.0 \
 -Dpackaging=jar \
 -DgeneratePom=true
```

### 3. Add the dependencies to your pom

```
<!-- These do not have a Maven repository -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
   <artifactId>virtjdbc4</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
   <artifactId>virt_jena3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**4. Add the information about the steps to your documentation**

**Alternatively** you could use the `<system>` scope to point to the jars, but this will generate problems if you want to create an uber-jar. If you still want to try, here is the fragment to add in the `<dependency>` tag

```
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>/path/to/jar/virtjdbc4.jar</systemPath>
```

Comment: Please also add your voice to [the relevant open issues on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/search?q=maven&state=open&type=Issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can download from this link [Virtuoso maven dependency](http://maven.aksw.org/repository/internal/com/openlink/virtuoso/).
Now, download the jar and related pom file from the directory and put it manually to maven repository directory of your computer location.

Comment: Please also add your voice to [the relevant open issues on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/search?q=maven&state=open&type=Issues).