# Maven virtuoso dependency not available

Tags: java, maven, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I've used the virtuoso in one of my projects before 1 year now the dependency won't work anymore

I have tried to search on the maven repository but not able to find. As I used the Openlink virtuoso at that time but now the dependency not able to download

Below is the dependency which I added.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
        <artifactId>virtjdbc3</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
        <artifactId>virt_jena</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anybody help me how do I get back this two library using maven or if you have any idea where it is located?

Comment: Check out this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137342/is-there-any-usable-dependency-for-virtuoso-jena-driver#answer-53674497)

Comment: Please also add your voice to [the relevant open issues on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/search?q=maven&state=open&type=Issues).